# Make Nivo LightBox specific to only a single video on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox

I am currently using Nivo LightBox script to have a popup effect on a video on my website. http://demo.dev7studios.com/nivo-lightbox/. 
I am a complete newcomer on jQuery and I am unable to make that lightbox be triggered only when pressing the link for my video. What the lightbox proposes is to have it work for every  link.
I tried using a #video tag with a corresponding id on my vid, but all it does is make my page completely blank...

Here is the code to be posted in the header :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a').nivoLightbox();
});
</script>
```

And here is the link I would like to popup:

```
<a class="button no-border" href="#" target="_blank">Watch now</a>
```

If anyone can help me with this I would greatly appreciate it :). And learn a thing or two in the process.

Thanks a bunch !

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Bit late with an answer...

The line that reads

```
$('a').nivoLightbox();
```

is what you are selecting to send to the nivoLightbox plugin.
Here you are saying "apply the plugin to every single a tag (link) in the document.

What you want to do is give your specific link some distinct feature, like an ID or class.

You could add class="nivo-link" to your link, then change the above line to

```
$('a.nivo-link').nivoLightBox();
```

This will then only apply it to links with that class on them and not everything else in the document.

Comment: Thanks a lot :). Better late than never ! I tried what you suggested. If I have an ID should I have called it : $('#nivo-link').nivoLightBox(); ?
I actually think my problems goes deeper... I can't put any script in the header otherwise my page goes blank... If I put them at the end of the body the page is still alive but the scripts don't seem to work. 
It annoys me a lot because the page has working jQuery... It is a template that comes with some jQuery in the code. Put the scripts I try to add don't work.
Anyway, thanks a lot for your input ! :)